# How to make selection highlight of list rows with different colors?

Tags: android, listview, selector

I have a question.

how to make highlight selection of row in List View by different colors? but I want to do it correct with list selectors.

Please provide some simple for few colors

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set up colors in your `Adapter.getView()` method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View result = ...
    // check convertView, inflate new layout, bla-bla-bla

    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        result.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.even);
    } else {
        result.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.odd);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: even and odd... are selectors?